# Gnome3 change theme per application

Tags: gnome3

Does anyone know what's application on the screenshot?
[image: screenshot1]
[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "GTK Inspector", a developer tool that's part of GTK 3. (Earlier known as "gtkparasite.") All changes you make within it are temporary and lost upon closing the program.

In most GTK 3 programs you can open it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>, or by running the program from command line as:

```
GTK_DEBUG=interactive appname
```

GTK 3 also lets you override just the theme, using:

```
GTK_THEME=themename appname
```